# Did Michael J. Fox write his own music for BttF?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, back-to-the-future, rock-music

In the original Back to the Future, Marty McFly tends to get carried away while playing his guitar, causing confusion and/or disapproval from any nearby squares.

The examples given of his overzealousness are:

- In Doc Brown's lab when he blew the speaker
- During the audition for his school's dance
- During the performance for his parent's school dance

According to Michael J. Fox's [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000150/bio?ref_=nm_ov_bio_sm) page, he

> Received his first guitar for Christmas when he was 8. He taught himself how to play.

**Given MJF's experience with playing guitar, was the shredding in the film of his own composition? If not, did he have any input on what his character would do in those situations?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [imdb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088763/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ov_st_sm) Alan Silvestri composed the music for the film, and Fox does not get credited with any incidental music, so I would assume that Silvestri gets credit for whatever Fox "played" (or more likely mimed). Paul Hanson is credited as Fox's guitar coach, but that typically implies helping him get the miming right, not helping him play the instrument. It's possible that Fox improvised the guitar for those sequences and that his improvisations were used, but I have not got a source claiming that that happened.